# how do I go about creating a basic database in Android studio that saves names with integer values

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

i want to allow the user to enter names and save them. then, the user is able to assign how many "wins" and "losses" each name has, so basically integer values associated with a string. I created a data class which registers one user's name and two integer values (which are initialized at zero).

the user enters the name in a text box widget which uses the onClickListener to call the function to save it in the class. but this just saves one name. how can i use the data class to save multiple names with their corresponding integer values by the input of the user into the textbox widget?

i feel like i am missing a fundamental concept of data classes and i don't even know what is the approach to achieving something like this. a list stores data but has only one dimension so to speak and a dictionary has only two dimensions. also, i feel that this can be done without SQL or anything that but I may be wrong.

any help/resources on this kind of thing is appreciated. here is some of the code:

```
data class playerData(val name: String, var wins: Int, var losses: Int){
        }

        fun register(playerBeingEntered: String) {
            val player1= playerData(playerBeingEntered,wins =0,losses=0)
            println(player1)
        }
        addPlayer.setOnClickListener{
            var playerBeingEntered:String = playerEntry.text.toString()
            playerEntry.text.clear()
            register(playerBeingEntered)
        }
```

Comment: You need to implement ROOM database for your application.

Comment: got it thank you! a lead like that is just what i needed.